# Why is it that $ \left(\sum_{j=1}^{N}\pi_jx_j\right)^2 = \sum_{j=1}^{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\pi_j \pi_kx_jx_k $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

In my Statistical Inference class, I came across the following:

$$ \mathbb{E}(Y^2) =\Bigl(\sum_{j=1}^{N}\pi_jx_j\Bigr)^2 = \sum_{j=1}^{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\pi_j \pi_kx_jx_k  $$

What I don't understand here is why a summation, when squared, becomes a double summation. In my head, the LHS would just be

$$ \Bigl(\sum_{j=1}^{N}\pi_jx_j\Bigr)^2 = \Bigl(\sum_{j=1}^{N}\pi_jx_j\Bigr)\Bigl(\sum_{j=1}^{N}\pi_jx_j\Bigr)$$

Comment: So far so good. When you continue, you will have $x_1x_1+x_1x_2+... $ which can be reduced to double summation. Try it with $N=2$.

Comment: I have understood it with the $N = 2$ example.

Comment: $$\Bigl(\sum_{j=1}^{N}\pi_jx_j\Bigr)\Bigl(\sum_{j=1}^{N}\pi_jx_j\Bigr)=\Bigl(\sum_{j=1}^{N}\pi_jx_j\Bigr)\Bigl(\sum_{k=1}^{N}\pi_kx_k\Bigr)$$ Multiplying a sum with another sum means summing all possible products. The double sum is just a symbol for the "sum over all possible combinations of $j$ and $k$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just distributing one by one so we have

$$ \sum_j \pi _j x_j \sum_j \pi_j x_j = \pi_1x_1(\sum_j\pi_jx_j)+...+\pi_Nx_N(\sum_j\pi_jx_j)$$

Now this is much easier to work with, so lets bring those factors inside the $N$ summations. that is why we get $ \sum_k\sum_j \pi_j\pi_kx_jx_k$.